# How do you pass an encoding to odo when loading a csv file?

Tags: python, blaze, odo

The odo documentation is quite sparse, it does not explain how to pass further parameters when, say loading a csv file. For example, how do I tell odo that the file is latin1 encoded?

```
data=[]
odo('mylatin1.csv',data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `encoding` keyword argument:

```
data = []
odo('mylatin1.csv', data, encoding='latin1')
```

Alternatively, try specifying the encoding using `odo.resource`:

```
from odo import resource

my_csv = resource('mylatin1.csv', encoding='latin1')
data = []
odo(my_csv, data)
```